# What is the Baasbox database system?

Tags: mongodb, rest, backend

Anyone know which database runs on [BAASBOX](http://www.baasbox.com/)?

Is this MongoDB?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [its code](https://github.com/baasbox/baasbox), looks like it uses [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/).